# Call API sequentially until response is empty

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to call an API continuously and count through the pages until the response is empty. Each page returns a maximum of 1000 'results' until eventually returning only `[]`.

I've had an attempt at the below code but the while loop continues indefinitely and the flag is never set to false, despite the fact that I know page 5 returns empty.

```
 var count = 1;
 var flag = true;
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

 while (flag == true) {
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.example.net/results/?page=' + count, true);
    count++;
    request.onload = function () {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      if (data.length == 0) {
        flag = false;
      }
    }
    request.send();
 }
```

Comment: by the time first request is opened, the loop is already finished. A in AJAX stands for asynchronous. What you have to do is call the next request at the completion of the first and so on.

Comment: use something like recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the code is *asynchronous*. In particular, the `onload` callback only fires when the response is received, some time after the call is made. Your script doesn't stop running to "wait" for the response, so it continues ploughing through the loop, because `flag` is still `true`. By the time an "empty" response comes and `flag` becomes false, the loop will have run potentially thousands of times, setting up "useless" Ajax requests.

@AmitJoki already suggested how to fix this. Here is one way to do it (using recursion as suggested by @PranavCBalan - although I had already started writing this when I saw his comment :-) ):

```
function sendRequest(count) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.example.net/results/?page=' + count, true);
    request.onload = function () {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      if (data.length > 0) {
        sendRequest(count+1);
      }
    }
    request.send();
}

sendRequest(1);
```

The key difference is that, after sending one request, this code won't send another one until the response is back and confirmed to have `data.length` greater than 0.