# Recommended pattern to page through API response until exhausted?

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm new to Node and the async programming model. I'm having problems dealing with a simple requirement that seems pretty basic in synchronous environments: paging through an API response until the response is empty.

More specifically, the API, on a successful call, will return data and a status of 200 or 206 (partial content). If I see the 206 response, I need to keep making calls to the API (also sending a `page` query param that I increment each time) until I see the 200 response.

In a synchronous language, the task will be a piece of cake:

```
// pseudocode
data = []
page = 1
do {
    response = api.call(page)
    data.append(response.data)
    page++
} while (response != 200)

return data
```

Now, in Node, for a single api call, code like this will work:

```
// fire when '/' has a GET request
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    axios.get('https://api.com/v1/cats')
        .then(response => {
            // now what??
        });
    });
});
```

See the `//now what??` comment? That's the point where I'm wondering how to proceed. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281861/call-api-sequentially-until-response-is-empty) somewhat-relevant post but am not able to convert this to a format that will work for me in Node and Axios.

Is it enough to just wrap the axios code in a separate function? I don't think so, because if I do this:

```
function getData(pageNum) {
    axios.get('https://api.com/v1/cats')
        .then(response => {
            // now what??
        });
    });
}
```

I can't rely on a return value because as soon `axios.get()` gets executed, the function will be over. I can call `getData()` again after I get the first response, but then, suppose I want to return all the data from these multiple calls as the HTTP response from my Express server . . . how do I do that?

I hope I will not get downvoted for laziness or something. I've really looked around but not found anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a counter-question: Is the data set so big that you need to worry about using up all the memory? Because if so then it will take more work to structure your code in a way that streams the data all the way through. (In fact I'm not even sure whether express allows streaming... you are using express aren't you?)

From the axios documentation, it looks like `response` is a readable stream which provides the response body. So reading it is also an asynchronous task. So you should write a function that does that. See the "Stream" page of the nodejs docs for more details. Or I could be persuaded to help with that too, time permitting. But for now, I'll assume you have a function `readResponse`, which takes an axios response object as an argument and returns a promise, and the promise resolves to an object such as `{ statusCode: 206, result: ['thing1', 'thing2'] }`. I'll also assume that your goal is to get all the `result` arrays and concatenate them together to get e.g. `['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4', 'thing5', 'thing6']`.

You could write a self-calling version of your `getData` function. This will retrieve all data from a given page onwards (not just the page itself):

```
function getData(pageNum) {
    axios.get('https://api.com/v1/cats' + (pageNum ? '?page=' + pageNum) : '')
        .then(readResponse)
        .then(function(parsedResponse) {
            if(parsedResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                return parsedResponse.result;
            } else if(parsedResponse.statusCode == 206) {
                return getData(pageNum + 1).then(function(laterData) {
                    return parsedResponse.result.concat(laterData);
                });
            } else {
                // error handling here, throw an exception or return a failing promise.
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then, to get all data, just call this function with `pageNum = 0`:

```
// fire when '/' has a GET request
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    getData(0)
        .then(function(results) {
            // results is now the array you want.
            var response = JSON.stringify(results);   // or whatever you're doing to serialise your data
            res.send(response);
        });
});
```

Comment: Ah, so the solution was through recursion after all! I got this sense when thinking about the problem and browsing through the questions, but wasn't sure how I'd use it. Thank you also for demonstrating how to collect data from all requests. To answer your counter-question: No, memory isn't a concern here. It's a typical run-of-the-mill RES API that spits out ~250KB in response, and isn't expected to have more than 20-25 iterations.