# Do / While XMLHttpRequest add results of all calls to one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, do-while

I need to loop through N pages using a tag similar to `&page=N`, get specific IDs from those pages and in the end append values missing from a final array held by an object in local storage.

Since there can be over a hundred pages or more I cannot just do a For or Do / While loop since all of the requests would happen at once, overwhelming the server.

Anyways, I found a solution that waits for one request to be done before firing another one. It works as expected (however I feel it's a huge workaround, rather than a good solution).

The issue is that I would like each request to concat the result array to a "master array" of all the results from all the pages scraped which I would like to compare to what's in local storage only after all the requests run. And it is not happening... Would it make more sense to do it per request?

Here's the code:

```
function getUserRatings() {
    storage.get("userID", function(result) {
        if (!isEmpty(result)) {
            var pageNo = 1
            var finalArr = [];
            do {
                (function(cntr) {
                    let resp = requestRatings("https://www.page.com/user/" + result["userID"] + "/info/page-" + pageNo.toString() + "/");
                    resp.then((successMessage) => {
                        finalArr.concat(successMessage);
                        console.log("requestJSON(JSONURL) finished ", successMessage);
                        console.log("finalArr ongoing = ", finalArr);
                    });
                    pageNo++;
                })(pageNo);
            }
            while (pageNo <= 7); // temporary - need to replace this with sth like 'while any of the values in the returned array are not found in local storage array
        }
    });
}

function requestRatings(url) {
    console.log("requesting ratings");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                var rspns = xhr.responseText;
                var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rspns, "text/html");
                //console.log(doc);
                var ratedList = doc.querySelectorAll('a[class~="specificClass"]');
                var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(ratedList, function (e) {return e.getAttribute('href').replace(/(?:.*?stuff\/|-[^$]+)/gm, '')});
                //console.log(arr);
                resolve(arr);
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

What I consider to be the workaround part is the `function(cntr)` and this I also suspect to be the reason for the issue I'm having of the array not being concated.

Despite the `finalArr` variable being declared outside of the do / while loop, it is not updated (probably because the concat happens in a separate function?).

.

Here is the full solution I would like to achieve:

- Loop through pages one by one so not to overwhelm the server
- Capture array the request returns
- If any of the values in the returned array already exists in the array saved in local storage, stop looping (the data on the page is sorted, so if I come across an existing value, it means all the values after that one are already stored and don't need to be scraped again)
- Concat the returned arrays to a master array
- Remove values from the master array that are already in the local storage array
- Append the updated master array to the local storage array

EDIT: i figured out how to do the http requests one by one. The unfortunate thing is that the requests do not run sequentially. Any ideas how to make it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this which helped me with sequential http requests - recursion - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55282152/4017077.

How I have it set up:

- Load first page, get response
- Get required array of ids from the response
- Concat the array of ids with the storage array
- Remove duplicates (this is for the time once all the ids are saved and I'm checking the first page (with newest ids) again)
- save it to local storage
- If none of the ids in the array is present in the storage array, then call the function again from within the function with a +1 page number